# matlab gui radio buttons

Tags: matlab, user-interface, radio-button

I am trying what @Amro suggested me and I changed part of the code and I got some errors :/

please help me.

I set the Options to be:

```
options = {
    {'r','g','b','c','m','y','k'} ;
    {'x','o','.','s'} ;
    {'1','2','3'} ;
    {'2','3'} ;
    {'1','3'} ;
    {'1','2'}
};
```

now, I wrote in matlab:

```
mainGUI(options)
```

and I got these errors:

```
??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> tmp>secondaryGUI at 67
        if strcmp(selected{i},options{i}{j})

Error in ==> tmp>callback at 17
    hOptsGUI = secondaryGUI(hFig);

??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

This is the code:

```
function  mainGUI(options)
    %# current options
    opts = {'r', '.', '1'};

    %# create main figure, with plot and options button
    hFig = figure;
    callback

    %# options button callback function
    function callback(o,e)
        %# save current options (sharing data between the two GUIs)
        setappdata(hFig, 'opts',opts);

        %# display options dialog and wait for it
        hOptsGUI = secondaryGUI(hFig, options);
        waitfor(hOptsGUI);

        %# get new options, and update plot accordingly
        opts = getappdata(hFig, 'opts');
        opts
    end
end

function hFig = secondaryGUI(hParentFig, options)
    %# create figure
    hFig = figure('Menubar','none', 'Resize','off', ...
    'WindowStyle','modal', 'Position',[100 100 350 200]);
    movegui(hFig, 'center');

    %# all possible plot options

    options = cellfun(@(c) c(end:-1:1), options, 'Uniform',false);
    num = length(options);

    %# get saved settings
    selected = getappdata(hParentFig, 'opts');

    %# top/bottom panels
    hPanBot = uipanel('Parent',hFig, 'BorderType','none', ...
    'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0.0 1 0.2]);
    hPanTop = uipanel('Parent',hFig, 'BorderType','none', ...
    'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0.2 1 0.8]);

    %# buttongroups in top panel
    hBtnGrp = zeros(1,num);
    width = 1/num;
    for i=1:num
        %# create button group
        hBtnGrp(i) = uibuttongroup('Parent',hPanTop, ...
            'Units','normalized', 'Position',[(i-1)*width 0 width 1]);
        %# populate it with radio buttons
        height = 1./numel(options{i});
        for j=1:numel(options{i})
            h = uicontrol('Parent',hBtnGrp(i), 'Style','Radio', ...
            'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0.05 (j-1)*height 0.9 height], ...
            'String',options{i}{j});
            %# set initially selected values
            if strcmp(selected{i},options{i}{j})
                set(hBtnGrp(i), 'SelectedObject',h)
            end
        end
    end

    %# save button in bottom panel
    uicontrol('Parent',hPanBot, 'Style','pushbutton', ...
        'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0.3 0.2 0.4 0.6], ...
        'String','start', 'Callback',@callback)

    %# save button callback function
    function callback(o,e)
        %# get selected values
        hObjs = get(hBtnGrp(:), 'SelectedObject');
        vals = get(cell2mat(hObjs),{'String'});

        %# update settings
        setappdata(hParentFig, 'opts',vals);

        %# close options dialog
        close(hFig)
    end
end
```

maybe there is a problem with the variable 'opts', because there are no values of: {'r', '.', '1'} ?

cause I dont know why it exceeds matrix dimensions, the length of options is 6.

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood this correctly, you are designing a GUI that enables the user to set some parameters and return the selected options.

Instead of returning a value immediately as you are doing now, you can use [GETAPPDATA](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/getappdata.html)/[SETAPPDATA](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/setappdata.html) as data sharing mechanism.

As for the layout, use [panels](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uipanel.html) to group components together, this allows for more flexible GUIs.

Here is a sample application to illustrate. The idea is that we have the main figure containing a plot, and we provide a second "dialog" to customize the plot options.

```
function mainGUI()
    %# current options
    opts = {'r', '.', '1'};

    %# create main figure, with plot and options button
    hFig = figure;
    hLine = plot(cumsum(rand(100,1)-0.5), ...
        'Color',opts{1}, 'Marker',opts{2}, 'LineWidth',str2double(opts{3}));
    uicontrol('Style','pushbutton', 'String','Options...', 'Callback',@callback)

    %# options button callback function
    function callback(o,e)
        %# save current options (sharing data between the two GUIs)
        setappdata(hFig, 'opts',opts);

        %# display options dialog and wait for it
        hOptsGUI = secondaryGUI(hFig);
        waitfor(hOptsGUI);

        %# get new options, and update plot accordingly
        opts = getappdata(hFig, 'opts');
        set(hLine, 'Color',opts{1}, 'Marker',opts{2}, 'LineWidth',str2double(opts{3}))
    end
end

function hFig = secondaryGUI(hParentFig)
    %# create figure
    hFig = figure('Menubar','none', 'Resize','off', ...
        'WindowStyle','modal', 'Position',[100 100 350 200]);
    movegui(hFig, 'center');

    %# all possible plot options
    options = {
        {'r','g','b','c','m','y','k'} ;    %# color
        {'x','o','.','s'} ;                %# shape
        {'1','2','3'}                      %# width
    };
    options = cellfun(@(c) c(end:-1:1), options, 'Uniform',false);
    num = length(options);

    %# get saved settings
    selected = getappdata(hParentFig, 'opts');

    %# top/bottom panels
    hPanBot = uipanel('Parent',hFig, 'BorderType','none', ...
        'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0.0 1 0.2]);
    hPanTop = uipanel('Parent',hFig, 'BorderType','none', ...
        'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0.2 1 0.8]);

    %# buttongroups in top panel
    hBtnGrp = zeros(1,num);
    width = 1/num;
    for i=1:num
        %# create button group
        hBtnGrp(i) = uibuttongroup('Parent',hPanTop, ...
            'Units','normalized', 'Position',[(i-1)*width 0 width 1]);
        %# populate it with radio buttons
        height = 1./numel(options{i});
        for j=1:numel(options{i})
            h = uicontrol('Parent',hBtnGrp(i), 'Style','Radio', ...
                'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0.05 (j-1)*height 0.9 height], ...
                'String',options{i}{j});
            %# set initially selected values
            if strcmp(selected{i},options{i}{j})
                set(hBtnGrp(i), 'SelectedObject',h)
            end
        end
    end

    %# save button in bottom panel
    uicontrol('Parent',hPanBot, 'Style','pushbutton', ...
        'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0.3 0.2 0.4 0.6], ...
        'String','Save & Close', 'Callback',@callback)

    %# save button callback function
    function callback(o,e)
        %# get selected values
        hObjs = get(hBtnGrp(:), 'SelectedObject');
        vals = get(cell2mat(hObjs),{'String'});

        %# update settings
        setappdata(hParentFig, 'opts',vals);

        %# close options dialog
        close(hFig)
    end
end
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi and thank you very much for your comment, but it is not what I need exactly :/ I tried to ask it again, so can you read my question again please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775243/matlab-gui-buttons

Comment: @AlonShmiel: The other question is almost identical, and I still don't get what it is you want to do (always [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) specific questions)... I tried to address all the problems you mentioned. So if nothing else, study the code above and maybe you will get an idea for the solution. I made sure to comment every step, so it should be easy to follow.

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested me. I just need the 'figure 2' window, so I delete the 'figure 1' window. I change my new question. If you can, please help me. thank you alot, Alon.